# What is the chance that the fourth person is a woman

Tags: probability

A population consists of 25 men and 25 women. A simple random sample (draws at random without replacement) of 4 people is chosen. Find the chance that in the sample:
a)the fourth person is a woman
b)the third person is a woman, given that the first person and fourth person are both men

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine drawing people, one after the other, until we have drawn all $50$. Then all orderings of the people are **equally likely.**

So the probability the fourth person is a woman is the same as the probability that the first person is a woman, which is $\frac{25}{50}$.

Similarly, the probability that the third person is a woman, given that the second and fourth are men, is the same as the probability the third is a woman, given the first two are men. This is $\frac{25}{48}$.

Comment: +1 Nice approach. Mine would have been woefully computational.

Comment: @copper.hat: But it is worthwhile to do the computation, and after a certain amount of work reach $1/2$. I think that was the pedagogic point Alex is making.

Comment: Well, the computation supplies confirmation, but no intuition. Viewing the sample space as all permutations simplifies and elucidates at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Denote $0$ for man and $1$ for woman. $S$ is an event that 4th person is a woman. Obviously 8 cases for the first 3 tosses are possible: $\{000,001, \cdots ,111\}$. Hence you have to use the law of total probability:
$$
P(S)= P(S|000)P(000) + P(S|001)P(001)+ \cdots +P(S|111)P(111)
$$

The answer to the second question should follow easily